# How to update the cygwin offline installation folder

Tags: upgrade, cygwin

I am using a Windows 10 with cygwin installed on it and also need to install cygwin on a series of machines that have no internet access

The solution I found is to run the cygwin setup program, and select "download without installing" (or something of the sort)

I had done that a few months ago and now I need to do it again, but I need to have the last version of cygwin, and I can't find a way to update the current offline installer nor download a new one

How can I do that?

Thank you all in advance for your replies

Cheers,